# Reading Dates/Times from a SAS file: read_sas vs. read.SAS7bdat

Tags: r, shiny, sas, r-haven

I am trying to replace the read.SAS7bdat function with read_sas from the haven package in a number of my programs due to speed.  Simply substituting it in works perfectly and reads so much quicker.  However, the only hang-up I encounter has to deal with dates and times.  For some reason, I can no longer subset by a date selected in an R Shiny date input even though the underlying data looks the same and all other functions work.  If anyone knows of a difference between how these two functions read dates that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show an example of the generated R object from the two different reads and the R properties of the two different variable/object/column created from the SAS variable with date values.

Comment: Is the type of the date variable the same across your data sets? Is it Date, Num, Char?

Answer (score 0):

Date zero in SAS is 1 Jan 1960, and in R (origin date) it is 1 Jan 1970. That might be the reason for your issue. Bring in dates as character from SAS, and then convert it to numeric in R.

Comment: Thanks! This was one of the two issues

Comment: @YBS Old thread, but how would one bring in dates as character from SAS (using read_sas)? Is there somewhere to specify that in one of the argument options? My dates are being read into R through using read_sas as numeric and I would like to get them read in as character.

Answer (score 0):

There were two components: first I had to change the origin date to 1970 instead of 1960 as I previously was using with read.sas7bdat.  I also had previously converted everything to a POSIX date, which worked fine.  However, subsetting by an R shiny date input wasn't working with read_sas so I converted the posix using as.date and this resolved it.  Not exactly sure why though.